# Excel VBA no screenupdate when use Worksheet_Activate()

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have made a macro which collapses an certain number of columns based on an input sheet. The macro is running, when the user is activating the sheet(s), as seen below.

Worksheet_Activate macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "mypassword"

Call collapsecolumns

ActiveSheet.Protect "mypassword"

End sub
```

The macro which is called:

```
Public Sub collapsecolumns()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("inputSheet")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
Dim sheetNo As Integer, colToCollapse As Integer

'number in sheet name define range for counting columns to collapse
sheetNo = Right(ws2.Name, 1) 

'input range differs depending on which sheet is chosen
colToCollapse = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws1.Range("J" & ((6 * sheetNo) - 4) & ":J" & ((6 * sheetNo) + 1)))

ws2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 35)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False

If colToCollapse = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ws2.Range(Cells(1, colToCollapse * 6), Cells(1, 35)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

However, when the sheet is activated, you seen the columns collapse (or uncollapse) depending on what you wrote in the other sheet. I've various combination and placements of ScreenUpdate=False and EntireEvents=False to mask the collapsing, but without success

Is there any way, that the user first sees the sheet, when the columns have been collapsed, when using Worksheet_Activate()?

Answer (score 1):

I have added two lines of code so that the user can view when the columns get hidden

```
Public Sub collapsecolumns()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("inputSheet")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
    Dim sheetNo As Integer, colToCollapse As Integer

    'number in sheet name define range for counting columns to collapse
    sheetNo = Right(ws2.Name, 1)

    'input range differs depending on which sheet is chosen
    colToCollapse = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws1.Range("J" & ((6 * sheetNo) - 4) & ":J" & ((6 * sheetNo) + 1)))

    ws2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 35)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    If colToCollapse = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 32
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
    ws2.Range(Cells(1, colToCollapse * 6), Cells(1, 35)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

It will first move the excel sheet to the columns which will hide
then it will wait for 1 second and then hide the columns

I hope this is what you were looking for...